# Getting rid of for loops in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Here is a problem that involves a `factorial`. For a given number, `n`, find the answer to the following:

```
(1 / n!) * (1! + 2! + 3! + ... + n!)
```

The iterative solution in Scala is very easy – a simple for loop suffices.

```
object MyClass {

def fsolve(n: Int): Double = {
    var a: Double = 1
    var cum: Double = 1
    for (i <- n to 2 by -1) { 
        a = a * (1.0/i.toDouble)
        cum += a
    }
    scala.math.floor(cum*1000000) / 1000000
}

def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(fsolve(7))     // answer 1.173214
}
```

}

I want to get rid of the for loop and use a `foldLeft` operation. Since the idea is to reduce a list of numbers to a single result, a `foldLeft`, or a similar instruction ought to do the job. How? I’m struggling to find a good Scala example I can follow. The code below illustrates where I am struggling to make the leap to more idiomatic Scala.

```
object MyClass {

    def fsolve(n: Int) = {
        (n to 2 by -1).foldLeft(1.toDouble) (_*_)
        // what comes next????
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println(fsolve(7))
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or pointers to a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is returned from `foldLeft`, like this:

```
val cum = (n to 2 by -1).foldLeft(1.toDouble) (_*_)
```

Only in your case the function needs to be different, as the fold above would multiply all `i` values together. You will pass both `cum` and `a` values for the folding:

```
def fsolve(n: Int): Double = {
  val (cum, _) = (n to 2 by -1).foldLeft(1.0, 1.0) { case ((sum, a),i) =>
    val newA = a * (1.0/i.toDouble)
    (sum + newA, newA)
  }
  scala.math.floor(cum*1000000) / 1000000
}
```

Comment: This solution works for large and small numbers, e.g. 200. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you have provided maps very nicely to the `scanLeft` function. It works sort of like a combination of `foldLeft` and `map`, running the fold operation but storing each generated value in the output list. The following code generates all of the factorials from `1` to `n`, sums them up, then divides by `n!`. Note that by performing a single floating point division at the end, instead of at every intermediate step, you reduce the odds of floating point errors.

```
def fsolve(n: Int): Double =
{
  val factorials = (2 to n).scanLeft(1)((cum: Int, value: Int) => value*cum)
  scala.math.floor(factorials.reduce(_+_)/factorials.last.toDouble*1000000)/1000000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to implement a solution without filling in the blanks but by proposing a different approach.

```
def fsolve(n: Int): Double = {
  require(n > 0, "n must be positive")
  def f(n: Int): Long = (1 to n).fold(1)(_ * _)
  (1.0 / f(n)) * ((1 to n).map(f).sum)
}
```

In the function I make sure to fail for invalid input with `require`, I define factorial (as `f`) and then use it by simply writing down the function in the closest possible way to the original expression we wanted to implement:

```
(1.0 / f(n)) * ((1 to n).map(f).sum)
```

If you really want to fold explicitly you can rewrite this expression as follows:

```
(1.0 / f(n)) * ((1 to n).map(f).fold(0L)(_ + _))
```

Also, please note that since all operations you are executing (sums and multiplications) are commutative, you can use `fold` instead of `foldLeft`: using the former doesn't prescribe an order in which operation should run, allowing a specific implementation of the collection to run the computation in parallel.

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/meainfxtSz2sulWGBMiH3g).

Comment: Just a note: The complexity of this solution is O(N^2), because of the way how factorial is computed. The original code was O(N). This may or may not be a problem depending on use.